# Can't Mark Player on Board

Tags: python

I am trying to create a game but am having problems getting the player's mark to appear on the board by using the player's current score as an index in the list that creates the board game.

```
class board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [36,35,34,33,32,31,
                      25,26,27,28,29,30,
                      24,23,22,21,20,19,
                      13,14,15,16,17,18,
                      12,11,10,9,8,7,
                      1,2,3,4,5,6]

        self.playerscore = 0

    def make_grid(self):
             print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[35],self.board[34],self.board[33],self.board[32],self.board[31], self.board[30]))
    print("|          |           |         |   C3      |   L3      |        |")       
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[24],self.board[25],self.board[26],self.board[27],self.board[28], self.board[29]))
    print("|          |   L4      |         |   C2      |           |        |")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[23],self.board[22],self.board[21],self.board[20],self.board[19], self.board[18],))
    print("|   L4     |   C1      |   C3    |   L2      |   C2      |        |")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[12],self.board[13],self.board[14],self.board[15],self.board[16], self.board[17],))
    print("|          |           |   L1    |           |           |        |")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[11],self.board[10],self.board[9],self.board[8],self.board[7], self.board[6],))
    print("|          |   C1      |         |           |    L2     |        |")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[0],self.board[1],self.board[2],self.board[3],self.board[4], self.board[5],))
    print("|          |    L1     |         |           |           |        |")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')

    def playermover(self):
        while self.playerscore < 36

            dice = input("Enter 1 to roll:")
            if dice == 1:
                self.playerscore = self.playerscore + randint(1,6)
                self.board[self.playerscore] = 'P'
            self.make_grid()
```

when I call the class I get the game board to appear and the input but every time I press 1 to roll the dice I just get the same board with no mark of where the player is.

Comment: `input` returns a string. You can cast it to an `int`... `if int(dice) == 1:`

Comment: Also `self.playerscore < 36` isn't doing anything... How does the `while` loop terminate?

Comment: Also also `self.board[self.playerscore] = 'P'` may throw an error since it's possible that `36 <= playerscore <= 41`. This is because you are adding a random int between 1 and 6 to a number `<= 35`.

Comment: I figures self.playerscore wasn't doing anything so I changed the while loop to while self.playerscore < 36

Comment: That's not what's in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not (or, at least show your) `from random import randint`.

As others have said, either convert your input to an int, or compare to the string.

You never instantiate the class, or call the methods.

You are making things way too complicated how you are setting up your board.

You also will want to set your board cell back to the correct number when the player leaves that space.

```
from random import randint

FINALSCORE = 36
class board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [i+1 for i in range(36)]

        self.playerscore = 0
        self.gameover = False

    def make_grid(self):
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s    |  %3s/C3   |  %3s/L3   |  %3s   |" % (self.board[35],self.board[34],self.board[33],self.board[32],self.board[31], self.board[30]))
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("|  %3s     |  %3s/L4   |  %3s    |  %3s/C2   |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[24],self.board[25],self.board[26],self.board[27],self.board[28], self.board[29]))
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("|  %3s/L4  |  %3s/C1   |  %3s/C3 |  %3s/L2   |  %3s/C2   |  %3s   |" % (self.board[23],self.board[22],self.board[21],self.board[20],self.board[19], self.board[18],))
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("|  %3s     |  %3s      |  %3s/L1 |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[12],self.board[13],self.board[14],self.board[15],self.board[16], self.board[17],))
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("|  %3s     |  %3s/C1   |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s/L2   |  %3s   |" % (self.board[11],self.board[10],self.board[9],self.board[8],self.board[7], self.board[6],))
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("|  %3s     |  %3s/L1   |  %3s    |  %3s      |  %3s      |  %3s   |" % (self.board[0],self.board[1],self.board[2],self.board[3],self.board[4], self.board[5],))
        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------')

    def playermover(self):
        dice = input("Enter 1 to roll:")
        if dice == '1':
            roll = randint(1,6)
            print(roll)
            if self.playerscore:
                self.board[self.playerscore-1] = self.playerscore 
            self.playerscore += roll
            if self.playerscore > FINALSCORE: self.playerscore = FINALSCORE
            if self.playerscore == FINALSCORE: self.gameover = True
            self.board[self.playerscore - 1] = 'P'
            print(self.playerscore)
        self.make_grid()


game = board()
game.make_grid()
while not game.gameover:
    game.playermover()
```

Comment: @James I agree that the method for displaying the grid is very cumbersome and "bulky".  However, in building a knowledge base for everyone to search, I feel that having an example that can be copy/pasted and run is important so that newer programmers can easily see what it is doing and then (hopefully) see how to apply the techniques to their issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string, not an integer.  So you have two choices.

Compare to a string like:

```
dice = input("Enter 1 to roll:")
if dice == '1':
```

Or convert to a int:

```
dice = int(input("Enter 1 to roll:"))
if dice == 1:
```

Comment: @alex, He asked why the counter was not advancing.

Comment: I tried converting to int but that didn't change the output